# Subscribe to event c#

Tags: c#, events, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an EventManager service which is rising an event.
I'm trying to subscribe to the event in a Razor page, and I can not manage to bind OnEvent method to the event. I'm using Blazor server.

Here is Dependency injection in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEventsManager, EventsManager>();
```

Here I have the service (transient) which is rising the event

```
public class EventsManager:IEventsManager
{

    public delegate void EventReceivedEvenHandler(EventsManager evManager, EventsView ev);
    public event EventReceivedEvenHandler EventReceived;


    public async Task ProcessEvents(List<Telemetry> telemetryList, string deviceProtocolId)
    {
            //Some code...

            var eventView = new EventsView()
            OnEventReceived(eventView);
    }

    public virtual void OnEventReceived(EventsView ev)
    {
            EventReceived?.Invoke(this, ev);
    }
}
```

Here I have a Razor page where I inject the service:

```
@inject IEventsManager eventManager



protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    eventManager.EventReceived += OnEventReceived;
}

public void OnEventReceived(EventsManager evMan,  EventsView ev)
{
 //some code
}
```

The program is running but public *event EventReceivedEvenHandler EventReceived* is always null.

Comment: Blazor Server Side or WebAssembly?

Comment: Blazor Server Side

Comment: And you are missing Dispose() and `-=` , this could be a big memory leak.

Comment: try service.AddSingleton<EventsManager>() in your configure

Comment: I have edit the post in order to inlude  DI.Is not an option to make EventsManager as singleton, becase i have DB injected olso in EventsManager and is not singleton.

Comment: In EventsManager I will recevie permanently some message/payloads from deviceis, and I will save them in DB (In EventsManager) and in the same time I want to send them to the UI.

Comment: For saving data in DB, indeed I'm using DbContextFactory which is scoped. App is multi-user. Each user will see messages for their devices. So In EventManager I will have a method which will filter the messages and provide to the UI only events releted to their devices.

Comment: Then you will need Scoped.

Comment: I've tried with scoped. The problem is, when I bind the subscriber here: eventManager.EventReceived += OnEventReceived; , nothing is happening. EventReceived it remains null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read your question correctly you have some background process capturing data.  This process raises events in the `EventsManager`.  Your `IEventsMansger` therefore has to be registered as a singleton for the background service and the UI to access the same instance.

As you are also doing DB operations, you need to separate them from `IEventManager`.  You can do that by handling the DB operations in a separate Scoped or Transient service.  That service injects the `IEventsManager`  and raises the events in the `IEventsManager`.

Here's a refactored version of your code.

The various objects.  I've made some guesses here.

```cs
public delegate void EventReceivedEvenHandler(EventsManager evManager, EventsView ev);

public interface IEventsManager
{
    public event EventReceivedEvenHandler EventReceived;
    public Task ProcessEvents(List<Telemetry> telemetryList, string deviceProtocolId);
    public void OnEventReceived(EventsView ev);
}

public class EventsManager : IEventsManager
{
    public event EventReceivedEvenHandler? EventReceived;

    public async Task ProcessEvents(List<Telemetry> telemetryList, string deviceProtocolId)
    {
        //Some async code...
        await Task.Yield();

        var eventView = new EventsView();
        OnEventReceived(eventView);
    }

    public virtual void OnEventReceived(EventsView ev)
    {
        EventReceived?.Invoke(this, ev);
    }
}

public class EventsView
{
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Telemetry { }
```

The new `EventsHandler` service:

```cs
namespace SO77374228.Data;

public class EventsHandler { 

    private IEventsManager _eventsManager;

    public EventsHandler(IEventsManager eventsManager)
    {
        _eventsManager = eventsManager;
        // get your Database stuff here
    }

    public async Task HandleEventAsync()
    {
        // Do your database saving here
        // You must use the DBContextFactory with using within the method to ensure correct handling of disposal of the context 
        await Task.Yield();
        //_eventsManager.ProcessEvents();
        _eventsManager.OnEventReceived(new() { Value = $"Hello at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} " });
    }

}
```

Service registration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEventsManager, EventsManager>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<EventsHandler>();
```

`Index` to display the data

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IEventsManager EventsManager
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="alert alert-primary">@_eventsView.Value</div>

@code {
    private EventsView _eventsView = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.EventsManager.EventReceived += this.OnEvent;

    private void OnEvent(object sender, EventsView eventsView)
    {
        _eventsView = eventsView;
        // as this is not a UI event we need to render the component to display any chnges
        this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    // Must Dispose properly
    public void Dispose()
        => this.EventsManager.EventReceived -= this.OnEvent;

}
```

And `Counter` to raise events.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@inject EventsHandler EventsHandler

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Raise an Event</button>

@code {

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        await this.EventsHandler.HandleEventAsync();
    }
}
```

And here's an image showing two browser windows open.  Click on the button and the event gets displayed in the other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed EventManager was scoped, and I was using one instance to receive messages and users was subscribing to other instances of EventManager. I've corrected this and new is working fine.