# Blazor realtime UI update variants

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am very new to blazor can't find an proper answer to the following topic:

**Use-Case:**
A blazor server app reads out a sensor value and displays this on the UI.
When the sensor value changes, the UI should be updated.

**Found solutions:**

a) Update the UI with a SignalR Hub, when the sensor value changes

razor component:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        sensorServiceHub= new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/sensorServiceHub"))
            .Build();
        sensorServiceHub.On("changed", () =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
        await sensorServiceHub.StartAsync();
    }
```

b) The sensor value is a property with an action delegate which is invoked on change. In the UI component we add a method to this delegate to update it.

razor component:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        SensorService.OnValueChanged += () =>
        {
            InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
        };
    }
```

**Question:**
When should i use which solution? Or are there other solutions?
I tried both variants and both worked. Is there a performance difference?
Sorry if the question is too basic...

Comment: "A blazor server app reads out a sensor value"  How?  What type of service?  In general that service should raise a standard event.  Any UI components the need to update when the value changes should register for that event.  On an event, do what they need to retrieve the value and call `StateHasChanged` to update the UI.

Comment: Both run on SignalR. The second sample uses the circuit that you already have so that'll be more efficient to run.

Comment: Updating and displaying data is obviously no problem.  But how are you collecting your data?  If you are using a barcode scanner, they are text devices (basically a special keyboard), so all you need to do is make sure that the page is focused on a text input, and you can use the @onchange event to process the scanned data.  But you'll have to tell us WHAT data you have and how it's collected.  If it's something more hardware-specific, you might want to use an API, so that your input isn't Blazor at all but. . . whatever works.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Why is it important how the data is collected? It is handled by the server and just have to inform the ui when something has changed. Anyway the server will have a connenction to a beckhoff plc, from where the data is read out.

Comment: B - you're using the existing session.  There's no reason to create another.  See this answer, which UI think is similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/77375594/13065781.