# Adding text box to Blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Starting from the sample Blazor application (with the counter and weather data), I want to add a text box to the side bar at the bottom and then write the counter value to it when the user clicks on the button on the counter page.

I come from an embedded C/C++ background with some C#, and so am fairly lost when it comes to HTML.

I have opened NavMenu.razor and found the NavMenuCssClass. I am guessing that whatever I add will be in a  under the fetch data item.

Edit 2: I am using .NET 6.0 and the Blazor Web Assembly App template

Edit 1:
I added <input type="text" @bind="TextBoxValue" placeholder="Enter text" /> to the end of the NavMenuCssClass and that got me my text box on the sidebar but I can't figure out how to access it from Counter.razor

```
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <input type="text" @bind="TextBoxValue" placeholder="Enter text" />
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    public string TextBoxValue { get; set; } = "";

    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you want to do would be fairly easy. But what .NET version are you using? What template did you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6.0, Blazor WebAssembly App

Comment: You want to loosely couple Counter.razor and the NavMenu.razor component so they communicate. You could inject a service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77375594/20339875 Also go through Blazor University pages: https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/

Answer (score 0):

When value change, you need to call stateHasChange to refresh the component. You could try following:
MainLayout.razor   (make a method to call statehaschange from child component)

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu TextBoxValue=@value.ToString() />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
</CascadingValue>

@code{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public void RefreshState()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Counter.razor (Add "CascadingParameter" attribute to pass value from child component to parent component)

```
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        Layout.value = currentCount;
        Layout.RefreshState();
    }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }
}
```

NavMenu.razor    (Add "parameter" attribute to pass value from parent component to child component)

```
...
        <input type="text" @bind="TextBoxValue" placeholder="Enter text" />
    </nav>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TextBoxValue { get; set; } = "";
...
```

Test
[image]